# show/hide div based on radio clicked with class

Tags: jquery, animation, radio-button

I have 4 radio buttons that correspond to 4 different divs.  i want to fadeOut the current div and then fadIn the new selected one. right now its working but just fades between images.

Also is there a way to change the divs based on the radio's class and not value?

Code I currently have:

```
<input type="radio" name="myRadio" class="myDiv_1" value="myDiv_1" />Image1<br />
<input type="radio" name="myRadio" class="myDiv_2" value="myDiv_2" />Image2<br />
<input type="radio" name="myRadio" class="myDiv_3" value="myDiv_3" />Image3<br />

<div id="myDiv_1" class="shade" style="display:block;"><img>TEXT BELOW IMAGE</div>
<div id="myDiv_2" class="shade" style="display:block;"><img>TEXT BELOW IMAGE</div>
<div id="myDiv_3" class="shade" style="display:block;"><img>TEXT BELOW IMAGE</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[name="myRadio"]').click(function() {
        var selected = $(this).val();
        $(".shade").fadeOut("slow");
        $('#' + selected).fadeIn("slow");
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can get the class of the object using jQuerys `attr` method:

```
var selected = $(this).attr("class");
```

Answer (score 2):

"i want to fadeOut the current div and then fadIn the new selected one"

Use fadeOut() callback function:

```
$(".shade").fadeOut("slow", function() {
    $('#' + selected).fadeIn("slow");
});
```

Comment: a callback doesnt work. when a radio button is clicked, it fades to the new div, but then the newly selected div fades out then back in. it basically is fading to many times. i can link to an example if need be.

Answer (score 1):

Just replace

```
var selected = $(this).val();
```

with

```
var selected = $(this).attr("class");
```

And the `div` faded in depends on the `class` attribute of the `input`.

Additionally I suggest using this (which should be faster)

```
$("div.shade:visible").fadeOut("slow");
```

instead of

```
$(".shade").fadeOut("slow");
```